# Flutter Google Sign In error - This App isn't verified error

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-oauth, google-signin

Deployed the flutter app in production, In google play console app got approved and now it's available in play store. But when user try to login using Google sign in, they are getting the below warning.

Already updated the SHA-1 key from google play console in firebase and downloaded the latest google-service.json file too.

Do i need to do something specific in play console for app to be verified?

What i am missing here. Please help me guys. My app is in production and users are getting this warning.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it can take a while to get updated. How long ago did you update the SHA-1 ?

Comment: It's been a week since i update the SHA-1 keys

Comment: This screen is related to your oauth2 consent screen.  Your app needs to be verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)

> An unverified app is an app or Apps Script that requests a sensitive or restricted OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process. Users of unverified apps or your test builds might get warnings based on the OAuth scopes you're using. This is to protect users and their data from deceptive apps.

On the Oauth consent screen in google cloud console, click prepare for verification.

[image]

Your application needs to go though the google verification process.

If you click the link for advanced you can by pass the warning and authorize the
application.

Before releasing your application to google play store you should have applied for verification this can take a while depending upon which scopes you have requested.

[Google hasn’t verified this app, what now? How to fix It!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6935WKdaH6E)